# How to setup programmable ram disk without root permissions on linux

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, ram

I need to setup and configure a ram-disk from within my C application. Is it possible?
From what I understand, a ram-disk can be setup, mounted and resized only by the root.
My application would not have that priviledge.
Is there any alternate to ram-disk which can be programmed, if it's not possible with ram-disk? 
The purpose is to get data available across multiple applications which run at different times and over the network. Since the data is huge(~100-150 GB), ram-disk implementation from within the application would keep the data in memory and the next application would just use it. This would save the expensive writing to and reading from the hard disk of the huge data.

Would appreciate help on this.

Edit: A little more clarity on the problem statement. Process A runs on machine1 and writes data of about 100GB on machine2 over NFS and exits. The process B runs on machine1 and reads this data (100GB) from machine2 over NFS. The writing and reading of this huge data is turning out to be the bottleneck. How can I reduce this?

Comment: 150 GB of data in a RAM disk? Doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: If you want data available to many applications on the same machine, I would suggest using an [mmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) call. Accessing the same memory over a network requires some additional work.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular file, but [memory map](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) it. That way, the second process can access it just as easily as the first. The OS caching will take care of keeping the "hot" parts of the file in RAM.

Update, based on your mention of NFS. Look for caching settings in Linux, increase them to be very, very aggressive, so the kernel caches and avoids writing back to disk (or NFS) as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use `shm_open` to create a **named** shared memory object, followed by `ftruncate` to set the size you need. You can then `mmap` part or all of it for writing, `close` it, and again `shm_open` it (using the same name) and `mmap` it in another process later. Once you're done with it, you can `shm_unlink` it.

Comment: where would this shared memory object reside when the first process that created it exits?

Comment: But once the process that created shared memory exits, the OS will release all the memory this process allocated and make it usable for other processes. Isn't that right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No. The memory is not released until you call `shm_unlink` on the name.

Comment: @user900563, R.. is right. I have never tried this on such a huge block of RAM, but I see no reason why it would not work.

Comment: There may be limits on how much you can allocate. On Linux, it would be controlled by the mount options for `/dev/shm`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you setup a ram-disk using admin tools and use it in your program as a normal filesystem. To share data between different processes you could use shared-memory.
I'm not sure what you want to achieve by loading 150GB into memory (are you sure you have that much RAM?).

Ten years ago, I tried to put c-header files into a ram-disk to speed-up compilation, unfortunatly this had no measureable effect, because the normal file system caches them already.

Comment: I cannot use shared memory since the both the processes run at different times. For shared memory, I would need the first process running when the 2nd process starts. Isn't that right? And yes, I have memory in the range of 100-150 GB.

Comment: At least on unix systems you can load data into a shared memory segment, and re-atach later by different processes independently of the creating process. (On windows I'm not sure about that). Since you have this huge amount of memory simple create a ramdisk and measure.

Comment: can I create ramdisk from within the process? Or can it be only done through kernel boot?

Comment: @user900563, you CAN use shared memory, as stacker said.

Comment: Got it! And can the size of shared memory be modified at run time?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for you would be to use use shared memory (e.g. with mmap). To circumvent the problem that your two process do not run at the same time introduce an additional process (call it the "ramdisk"-process). That runs permanent and keeps the memory map alive, while your other process can connect to it.

Comment: But shared memory is limited by an upper size. How to circumvent that?